# mysql query returning issue while using the comparison

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table with two fields

```
---------------
Qn  | ans
---------------
 1  |  2
---------------
 1  |  4 
---------------
 1  |  6 
---------------
 1  |  8 
---------------
 2  |  2
---------------
 2  |  4 
---------------
 2  |  6 
---------------
```

if am using the query to get the result as '1'  but because of the value in 2 its returning  1 and 2.

```
SELECT qn FROM tbl T1 WHERE T1.ans IN (2,4,6,8)
```

i need the result 1 , is there any other method to get the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT qn 
FROM tbl
WHERE ans IN (2,4,6,8)
group by qn
having count(distinct ans) = 4
```